How to solve log-log convex programs
I have a problem where the objective function is a posynomial and the constraints are linear (even if some coefficients of the variables in the constraints are non-positive), this problem can be considered a log-log convex problem. CVXPY toolbox does not directly support negative coefficients in the linear constraints.
 Maximize:
 f(x) = x_1*x_4+x_2*x_5+x_3*x_6 
Subject to:
  a^T x + b <= 1 
    0<= x <=ub 

I would be grateful if someone could guide on how to fix this problem.
How to solve and find solution of my problem

If the a coefficients can be negative then how is the problem log-log-convex?

F(u)=log f(e^u) for linear constraint be log-sum-exp, then is convex

Not with a negative coefficient.

yes, you are right. but   here i have problem with posynomial objective function with just linear constraints. So It's not LP, GP, and even LLCP. how to solve it?

@sorayamirzaei What are typical values for b and ub? What are typical ranges for a?

@Reinderien range of -100<a<100 and ub is positive up to 1000 , b can be zero in that case we have Ax=0.

Iterative solution
With a Jacobian specified, this solves quickly (10 iterations in the first case):
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize


def cost(x: np.ndarray) -> float:
    # Maximise x_1*x_4 + x_2*x_5 + x_3*x_6 + ...
    x0, x1 = x.reshape((2, -1))
    return -x0.dot(x1)


def jacobian(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    x0, x1 = x.reshape((2, -1))
    return -np.concatenate((x1, x0))


def optimise(a: np.ndarray, b: float, ub: float) -> np.ndarray:
    error = scipy.optimize.check_grad(
        func=cost, grad=jacobian, x0=np.linspace(start=0.5, stop=1.3, num=n),
    )
    assert np.isclose(error, 0, atol=1e-6, rtol=0)

    # a1x + a2x + a3x ... = 1 - b, same value for all x
    x0 = np.full_like(
        a, fill_value=(1 - b)/a.sum(),
    ).clip(min=0, max=ub)

    result = scipy.optimize.minimize(
        fun=cost, jac=jacobian, x0=x0,
        bounds=scipy.optimize.Bounds(lb=0, ub=ub),
        constraints=scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint(A=a, ub=1 - b),
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)
    return result.x


def demo() -> None:
    print(optimise(
        a=np.array((0.5, 3.3, 3.3, 0.5, 1.1, 1.2)),
        b=-7, ub=5,
    ))

    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    print(optimise(a=rand.random(size=20), b=-20, ub=5))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()

A better initial estimate may be:
    # Calculate sort order for a, in preparation to fill lowest positions in x0
    a_order = a.argsort()

    # The number of indices for which the cumulative sum is less than 1-b
    iub = (ub*a[a_order]).cumsum().searchsorted(1 - b)

    x0 = np.zeros_like(a)
    x0[a_order[:iub]] = ub

    slack = 1-b - a.dot(x0)
    if slack > 0 and iub < a.size:
        x0[a_order[iub]] = slack/a[a_order[iub]]

Non-iterative solution
Based on the modified initial estimate procedure shown above, it may be possible to

Reshape a to 2xn;
Sum over the first axis;
argsort;
Perform a bisection search as is done above;
Fill selected elements with the upper bound as is done above; and
Choose only one pair to set 0 < x < upper bound, with a deterministic value from a simple partial-derivative maximum

Whether this is possible depends fairly heavily on your actual values for b and ub.

thanks, but can you explain more about this methods? and by the way my problem contains more than 50,000 variables.

@sorayamirzaei This is a simplistic application of scipy's generic minimizer. It writes out a cost function and Jacobian naively. It probably won't scale to 50,000 variables.
